# Javascript: Accessing superclass objects from nested class

Tags: javascript

```
a = new function() {
    this.x=2;
    B=function() {
        this.y=super.x;
    }
    this.b=new B();
}

alert(a.b.y); // Expecting 2
```

In the above, there is a parse error in `super`. How can I access the value of x when defining the class B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best way to do this is to pass 'this' as the parameter in the constructor of the nested class, like this -

```
a = new function() {
    this.x=2;
    B=function(sup) {
        this.y=sup.x;
    }
    this.b=new B(this);
}

alert(a.b.y); // Displays 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This works but i'm not sure that your code is correct

```
a = new function() {
    var x=2;
    B=function() {
        this.y=x;
    }
    this.b=new B();
}

alert(a.b.y); //alerts 2
alert(a.x) //alert undefined becuase x is private
```

in any case there is no `super` in javascript, if you read [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) you can see how you could implement inehritance in javascript through a uber method